# Universal enveloping algebra of the Lie algebra of vector fields on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-algebras, differential-operators

Suppose we have a smooth manifold $M$ with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_M$ and $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is the Lie algebra of vector fields on $M$. How should we interpret the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{X}(M))$? Is it just the algebra of all (finite order) differential operators $\mathcal{O}_M \to \mathcal{O}_M$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't, because it does not contain the operators given by multiplication by a non-constant function.

You can view the Lie algebra as (part of) a Lie-Rinehart algebra, and then the corresponding enveloping algebra is indeed that of finite order differential operators.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, would the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{X}(M))$ correspond to the differential operators which have constant coefficients (in any local chart)?

Comment: No, because already the elements of $X(M)$ are not of that form!